# re-initialize array

Tags: c#, arrays, timer

How can I re-initialize an array?

```
public int[] numbers;
```

In my case `numbers` will be set with an unknown-length array. For example, when I use it first, it will have 8 elements, next time only 5, then 12.

I read some about this topic, and found only one relevant:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bee99ac8-4ade-40ac-aa78-8d14d1d7bf9f/c-reinitialize-arrays?forum=csharplanguage

Even if I do not care about the memory usage of redeclaration (uhh), I can't make it this way, since I'm going to use the array in a timer's thick method, and gonna use the same array, until the timer stops. Then call the function again, which would put the elements into the array, then start the timer again.

**Edit:**

There are 3 functions in my case and the array declare as a public variable. The first function is called doAction(), which calls another function which returns an array with unknown length. Then, doAction starts the timer1 (thick method), which needs to reach the array from doAction. That's the reason why I used a global variable to put the array in.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Can you please clarify what is wrong with `numbers=new int [5]`? Consider showing code instead of unclear "and gonna use the same array, until the timer stops".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use it first, do

```
numbers = new int[5];
```

when you use it again, do

```
numbers = new int[12];
```

If it's not that simple, then you haven't explained your problem very well.

Comment: What's gonna happen to the first array which was declared? Will it be overriden, or is it going to be there in the memory until GC removes it? Or are these different declarations? 

What I would like to do is to declare one array which can be accessed from anywhere within the class, and its length can be changed (I know length can't be changed directly, but I'm curious if there's a trick or something to solve this).

Comment: @KissKoppány length of array *can't be changed* (there is `List<int>` for it) so it is not exactly clear what you are looking for.

Comment: You're thinking about it wrong. `public int[] numbers;` does not allocate an array. It allocates a place where you could store an array. `numbers = new int[5];` allocates a 5-element integer array and stores it in `numbers`. `numbers = new int[12];` allocates a (different) 12-element integer array and stores it in `numbers`. Since nothing is now referencing the 5 element array, it will be available for GC.

Comment: That is okay, but I need to store the array in a global variable, in order to reach it from other function

Comment: Just do as you've already been told.  It will work.

Comment: Then go ahead and use the global variable.

Comment: Global variable does not work since I cant re-initialize it. I had to change the concept, now I'm using List instead of array. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Of _course_ you can re-initialize a global variable. Why didn't you try what you were told to try? Variables are _variable_.

Comment: @JohnSaunders ahhh okay now I got it. Somehow I misunderstood your answer, but it's clear now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do it that way.  You cannot change the size of an array.  When you stop the `Timer`, simply create a new array and assign it to the same variable.  It's the variable that matters.  You'll be getting the array from the variable in the `Tick` event handler so you'll always get the current array.